# tmux: Remap h, j, k, l to j, k, l, ; in copy-mode

Tags: tmux

I want to move in tmux copy mode with jkl; instead of hjkl.
How can I remap those key bindings?

I've tried:

```
unbind -T copy-mode-vi h;
unbind -T copy-mode-vi j;
unbind -T copy-mode-vi k;
unbind -T copy-mode-vi l;

bind -T copy-mode-vi j send-keys -X move-left;
bind -T copy-mode-vi k send-keys -X move-down;
bind -T copy-mode-vi l send-keys -X move-up;
bind -T copy-mode-vi \; send-keys -X move-right;
```

but it doesn't work. I suppose `move-left`, `move-down`, ... commands are not correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right about the `move-` commands being wrong, according to the tmux man page you want:

```
cursor-down
cursor-left
cursor-right
cursor-up
```